# How do I find Ubuntu drivers for my gigabyte GA-Z77-D3H motherboard?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, intel

I am going to build a computer and just ordered my parts. Here are my parts... 
http://pcpartpicker.com/user/jdabi13/saved/2AbA
Gigabyte, (the brand of my motherboard) says to find linux drivers from the chipset manufacturer, I cannot find the drivers on Intel's site (I have a Z77 chipset from Intel). Do I need to find drivers at all or do they come in the ubuntu kernel when I install it? I also have a Gigabyte brand graphics card made by NVIDIA, where do i find those drivers? Thanks if you can help

Answer (score 1):

Phoronix, a trusted source, indicated that [the Z77 works without trouble in Linux](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_z77_chipset&num=1). The drivers are built right into the kernel and will be automatically loaded at boot.

As for the nVidia card, just go to Software Sources > Additional Drivers and activate the driver and you will get OpenGL detection.

Comment: thanks, so I will I have to worry about the other stuff on the motherboard like the network interface card, usb, or audio?

Comment: The chipset stuff, no. At least, according to Phoronix, it should work out of the box. Intel is very good (*the best,* I find) with Linux compatibility, that's what I can tell you.